# I can't open Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: installation

I downloaded google chrome that was made for my computer from https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb. For some reason after I installed I can't open. Also in the corner where the time and other things are there's this red circle with a white dash in the middle of it. It says "An error occured, please run package manager from the right click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: 'Unknown Error:''(E:The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled,but I can't find an archive for it.)' This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal: `sudo apt-get install -f`

Follow next instructions.

Comment: I edited it but I can't even find it in there. But I did that command and I got,"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it." That file is in my downloads folder by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

You will want to reboot after using these commands. This can be done from the reboot menu, or by using this command in the terminal:

```
sudo reboot
```

You can open up a terminal by using CTRL+ALT+T or by using ALT+F2 and typing `gnome-terminal`.
That should fix the 'An error occurred, please run package manage' part.

Try using these commands to install chrome. This assumes that the google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb file is in your downloads folder:

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Please paste the output of those last commands.

Comment: I still got the same thing it's telling me, "E: The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: Does this fix the 'An error has occurred'?

Comment: Edited to include possible fix for google-chrome install.

Comment: evan@ubuntu:~$ cd Downloads
evan@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 168644 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace google-chrome-stable 27.0.1453.110-r202711 (using google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement google-chrome-stable ...
It's stuck on this.

Comment: It doesn't go any farther?

Comment: Try re-dowloading Chrome. You may have a corrupt archive.

Comment: It might just take a while. Give it 10 minutes, and if it isn't done by then, delete the archive, re download chrome, and try again.

Comment: That terminal was acting all weird so I closed it and restarted one it was still on that one but i'll re-download a new one right now.

Comment: Be sure to delete the .deb file before re-downloading so that you don't use the old .deb file.

Comment: Okay it's going past it now.

Comment: Be sure to use the last command after the second. If they both work, then google-chrome should be installed.

Comment: I don't even care about google chrome anymore it's just that my whole system is starting to act up from the install and i'll paste the terminal now. Google chrome is installed now and the software center is now working. Thank you so much, but I do still have that red circle in top right corner.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CCnVNgyz

Comment: From that log it looks like google-chrome has installed successfully. What other problems are you having?

Comment: Have you rebooted since using the commands in my post? I don't think the red button will go away without a reboot

Answer (score -2):

You can try removing the package completely first by doing:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -P google-chrome-stable
```